# Footer loading before images are loaded using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

I am new to ajax I want to load images first and then footer but when I am trying to load the images using ajax the footer gets loaded first instead of the images which makes the image overlap the footer. As you can see in the below image.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />     
    <title>Image Gallery</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "js/data.json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data)
            {
                $.each(data, function(i,pic){
                    $("ul.gallery").append("<li><img src='images/square/"+ pic.path + "' alt='" + pic.title + "'></li>");
                });
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log("Picture cannot be loaded");
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <style>
        .b-footer{
            background-color: #274472; 
            color:white;
        }
        .gallery {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        .gallery {
            list-style-type: none;
        }

        .gallery li{
            float: left;
            padding: 30px;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main class="container">     
        <ul class="gallery">
        </ul>
    </main>
    <footer class="text-center p-4 b-footer">
        This is a footer
        <div>
            <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
                <ol class="breadcrumb justify-content-center">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Browse</a></li>
                </ol>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </footer> 
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Can anyone help me out with how to resolve this issue like how to make the footer to be loaded later after the images are loaded? A correct code can help me.

Comment: I think your footer would be fine if you added a clearfix class to your main container. The reason is that all your li's are float left so your footer will overlap main. **.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}**

Comment: It worked thanks a lot

Comment: My pleasure, I've set my comment as an answer for anyone else who come along. If its good for you, try and set it as an approved answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your footer would be fine if you added a clearfix class to your main container. The reason is that all your li's are float left so your footer will overlap the main container.

```
.clearfix::after { 
    content: ""; 
    clear: both; 
    display: block; 
}
```

**SUMMARY**

> The clearfix, for those unaware, is a CSS hack that solves a
> persistent bug that occurs when two floated elements are stacked next
> to each other. When elements are aligned this way, the parent
> container ends up with a height of 0, and it can easily wreak havoc on
> a layout.

https://css-tricks.com/clearfix-a-lesson-in-web-development-evolution/

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what the issue was and what does this code does?

Comment: @Coderash I've edited my answer to contain the explanation and a reference link. Hope it helps

Comment: I have verified your answer. If you liked the question. Do upvote as I am completely new to this.

Answer (score 2):

It's not an ajax issue you just need to add proper footer CSS here is working solution of your problem just replace footer CSS with this

```
.b-footer{
                background-color: #274472; 
                color:white;
                position: absolute;
                 bottom: 0;
                width: 100%;
            }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />     
    <title>Image Gallery</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kQtW33rZJAHjgefvhyyzcGF3C5TFyBQBA13V1RKPf4uH+bwyzQxZ6CmMZHmNBEfJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
         $("ul.gallery").append("<li><img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQtfeR2gr_Z2U5rNiTKieMXMM9ZY96GbKUQQg&usqp=CAU'></li>");
        $.ajax({
            url: "js/data.json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data)
            {
              
                   
             
            },
            error: function() {
                 
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <style>
        .b-footer{
            background-color: #274472; 
            color:white;
            position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
                   width: 100%;
        }
        .gallery {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        .gallery {
            list-style-type: none;
        }

        .gallery li{
            float: left;
            padding: 30px;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .clearfix::after { 
    content: ""; 
    clear: both; 
    display: block; 
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main class="container">     
        <ul class="gallery">
        </ul>
    </main>
    <footer class="text-center p-4 b-footer">
        This is a footer
        <div id="footer">
            <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
                <ol class="breadcrumb justify-content-center">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Browse</a></li>
                </ol>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </footer> 
  </body>
</html>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Note:-**  for proper results see in full page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your website

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />     
    <title>Image Gallery</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "js/data.json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data)
            {
                $.each(data, function(i,pic){
                    $("ul.gallery").append("<li><img src='images/square/"+ pic.path + "' alt='" + pic.title + "'></li>");
                });
            },
            done: function() {
                $("#footer").show();
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log("Picture cannot be loaded");
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <style>
        .b-footer{
            background-color: #274472; 
            color:white;
        }
        .gallery {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        .gallery {
            list-style-type: none;
        }

        .gallery li{
            float: left;
            padding: 30px;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main class="container">     
        <ul class="gallery">
        </ul>
    </main>
    <footer class="text-center p-4 b-footer" id="footer" style="display:none;">
        This is a footer
        <div>
            <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
                <ol class="breadcrumb justify-content-center">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Browse</a></li>
                </ol>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </footer> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not displaying the footer

Comment: Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to remove existing styles for .gallery li  and add the below

```
.gallery li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 30px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden; }
```

Comment: This does not work.